# Ubuntu 18.04 fails to start in VirtualBox

Tags: startup

After I press the start icon on Ubuntu 18.04 in VirtualBox these messages appeared and Ubuntu fails to start!

Does it have any solution?
I have a lot of applications installed...

Best Regards

[image]

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/298367

Answer (score 0):

I found it with just unable the 3D acceleration in virtual box display screen settings.

Comment: "I found it with just **unable** the 3D acceleration": Do you mean "enable" or "disable"? Please [edit] your answer to correct it.